# Expect at least one of multiple elements in a xml response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, rspec, cucumber

I have an API endpoint, that returns an XML response. There's a part of that response that I want to test.

I have a `shop` model, that references another table called `shop_contact`, that may or may not be nil. It contains 3 columns, `email`, `phone` and `fax`

I'm mocking a couple of shops with fake contacts, and I want to test that the XML response `<shop_contact>`contains AT LEAST of these tags (be it, `<email>`, `<phone>`or `<fax>`) and it's not empty.

I tried:

```
hash = Hash.from_xml(response.body)
hash["shops"]["shop"].each do |shop|
    expect(shop["shop_contact"]["email"] ||
        shop["shop_contact"]["phone"] ||
        shop["shop_contact"]["fax"]).to_not be_empty
end
```

but I get this error:

`You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty? (NoMethodError)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.to_not be_empty` tests whether or not an array (or similar) has elements. So you could do this:

```
# construct an array
data = [
  shop['shop_contact']['email'],
  shop['shop_contact']['phone'],
  shop['shop_contact']['fax']
].compact # compact removes `nil` elements

expect(data).to_not be_empty
```

Or, if you want to stick with the `||`s:

```
expect(shop['shop_contact']['email'] ||
       shop['shop_contact']['phone'] ||
       shop['shop_contact']['fax']).to be_truthy
```